# How to interpret python bytes class when more than one byte in one \x

Tags: python, byte

In Python, I am struggling to understand the following bytes:

```
a = b'\xff33'
b = b'\x00333'
c = b'\x00gff'
```

According to Pycharm debugger, a has **3** bytes, b c have **4** bytes. I don't quite get why.

Why `b'\xff33' != b'\xff\x33'` and `b'\x00333' != b'\x00\x03\x33'`, and same logic for `c`

And `a b c` 's `hex()` conversion show:

```
a.hex() == 'ff3333'
b.hex() == '00333333'
c.hex() == '00676666'
```

I can't make sense of the results. Especially for `c.hex()`.  It seems g == 67 and f == 66... But then why a.hex() is ff not 6666.. I feel that my head is exploding.

Can you help me make sense of these?

Thanks

J

Comment: `\x` is an escape sequence, but the other characters just represent the bytes corresponding to their ascii value.

Comment: So consider `a`, the the escape sequence `\xff` represents the byte with value 255, i.e. "ff" in hexadecimal. However, `3` and `3` each represent a byte, since they aren't escaped with `\x`, and the value corresponds to the ascii value of the character `'3'`, i.e. `ord('3') == 51`. Thus, you have bytes `255 51 51`, which you can confirm by doing `list(a)`

Comment: Ah so \x only escape the first byte, and the rest of each char is an ascii value? That makes a lit of sense now.

Comment: I have a mmap read from a file that read out like this `\x99\x99\x99\xff33\xb3\xff\xcd `, which seems rather inconsistent to me. Why python decide to escape some character but display ascii for others... Why not just show everything per byte with \x escape.

Comment: Yes, you have to escape the bytes that are outside of the ascii range, of course, you can still use escape sequences for the whole thing, in other words, `b'\xff33' == b'\xff\x33\x33'`

Comment: It always shows the ascii value *if they are ascii printable and  in the ascii range*. So there's nothing inconsistent about it. The bytes there are: `[153, 153, 153, 255, 51, 51, 179, 255, 205]` all of those except 51 and 51, i.e. `b'33'` are outside the ascii range

Comment: I see that explained everything. Since you made the answer first please submit your answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 1):

Python's bytes uses a mix of escaped unprintable bytes and normal printable bytes.
`a` consists of the unprintable and escaped byte `\xff` and 2 printable `"3"`.
That would be `\xff\x33\x33` if one would escape all bytes, which is the same as the `.hex()` result.